# Tracking hashtag with geolocation - tweepy

Tags: python, geolocation, tweepy

I want to track all tweets of a particular hashtag but i need only the tweets with geolocation.
This line not working fine, the results are all tweets with geolocation.

```
stream.filter(track=["hashtag"],locations = GEOBOX_WORLD)
```

This work fine.

```
stream.filter(track=["hashtag"])
```

This work fine.

```
stream.filter(locations = GEOBOX_WORLD)
```

But the union of track and location don't work. There is some solution (without check tweet by tweet if .geo != None)?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a location filter to tweepy module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22889122/how-to-add-a-location-filter-to-tweepy-module)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't filter both things at once, you need to choose one and then check the other.
Here you can find a more detailed answer to a similar question: [How to add a location filter to tweepy module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22889122/how-to-add-a-location-filter-to-tweepy-module/22889470#22889470)