# Get location specific tweets from Twitter using Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, geolocation, tweepy, tweetstream

I'm trying to get tweets from a specific location using Tweepy but I get this error when I run the code

```
raise TweepError("Wrong number of locations points, "
tweepy.error.TweepError: Wrong number of locations points, it has to be a multiple of 4
```

In my code, I try to get tweets from New York City with the location coordinates for NY. How can I get tweets from NY alone? My guess is to use a range of coordinates say between x,y and y,z. How do I go about this?

Here is my code:

```
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
    """ A listener handles tweets are the received from the stream.
    This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.
    """
    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            print(data)
            saveFile = open('newtweets.csv', 'a')
            saveFile.write(data)
            saveFile.write('/n').encode("utf-8")
            saveFile.close()
            return True
        except BaseException:
            print ('failed ondata')
            time.sleep(5)

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status.encode("utf-8"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    #ASK FOR KEYWORD TO COLLECT DATA
    user_keyword=input("What keyword do you want to mine?")
    stream = Stream(auth, l)
    stream.filter(locations=[40.7127,74.0059], track=[user_keyword])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It needs 4 coordinates. NYC, for example:

`stream.filter(locations=[-74.1687,40.5722,-73.8062,40.9467])`

[Here](http://boundingbox.klokantech.com/)'s the first google result of a site that let's you draw bounding boxes.  Select CSV format on the bottom-left of the page.

It's important to note, as mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22889122/how-to-add-a-location-filter-to-tweepy-module), you cannot filter by both location AND keyword.