# Use Tweepy to gather Tweets with hashtags from Egypt

Tags: python, tweepy, twitter-streaming-api

I am using Tweepy and Python to gather tweets from Egypt.
**The tweets must contain hashtags.**

I am using these co-ordinates for Egypt:

```
25.13671875, 22.0245456012, 35.3759765625, 31.3723991049
```

The code is not a problem, but I am finding that I am only getting one or two tweets every few seconds, yet when I change the location to UK I get loaddsssss.

Anyone know whats going on please? Are my coordinates wrong?

Comment: nothing wrong with the coordinates. It could be due to several factors. time of day, number of active twitter users in Egypt, current events happening in Egypt, population, etc. Countries like the United States, United Kingdom, India, France and Canada have a much higher ratio of Twitter users than Egypt

Answer (score 0):

Some people may say RTFM... :-)

because according to the last [tweepy documentation](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#help-methods):

*The parameter value is specified by “latitude,longitude,**radius**”*

But in your example you set twice a GPS coordinates ...

So it explain the result you got, because in my opinion tweeter API understand your request like : 
"I would search all tweets, in a radius of 35.37mil (by default) near: 25.13671875, 22.0245456012"

So you may swich your coordinate request to :

```
25.13671875,22.0245456012,1000mil  #mil or km as you prefer
```

then It will be OK !

*To explain the diff.: latitude of England is around 50.85300: so the same request applied to England coord give you all tweets in a radius of 51mil near the central point you choose...

Best regards

Comment: lol. i am sure i read somewhere http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22889122/how-to-add-a-location-filter-to-tweepy-module that it takes a bounding box, and i know if i put in the co-ordinates for my area i see relevant tweets.

Comment: actually my code uses the .filter method, the documentation you refer to makes no mention of the filter method, it has a .search method...

Comment: That's because this documentation is for the RESTful API not the [Streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters) which *does* clarify you need a bounding box.

Comment: You are right Bender, I expected that you use RESTFul Api with the search method, but apparently you use streaming with filter, I added twitter-streaming-api tag to your question. Regards